# Postgresql BDR Update Update conflict detection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

Apparently only the new values of rows are sent between nodes on update.  So how can there ever be *detectable* conflict?   Node A receives an update from Node B, and a different update from node C.  How can A know that there was a conflict?  That the B and C updates were not conducted in some well defined order?

And what does "last-update-wins" mean?  Are the updates timestamped?  In which case does it rely on synchronized clocks?  Or does it just mean whichever update happens to get to Node A last wins?

SUMMARY

- Last Update Wins means based on commit time (requiring fairly synchronized clocks), and not the time a node sees an update.  So should be globally consitant.
- There aren't any Update/Update conflicts that are detectable (except constraint violations).  And they would be difficult to resolve if they were.
- Conflict resolution is row by row, not transaction by transaction.  Also see http://sdf.org/~riley/blog/2016/01/04/is-bi-directional-replication-bdr-in-postgres-transactional/

Comment: You may also want to check out https://groups.google.com/a/2ndquadrant.com/forum/#!forum/bdr-list . Also, note that I'm only able to respond to BDR quesitons on a limited basis: I'm busy developing the system, and also 2ndQuadrant has paid support services for BDR that need priority. So don't expect timely/detailed/long answers routinely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual](http://bdr-project.org/docs/stable/conflicts-types.html) discusses much of this.

Yes, commits are timestamped. Conflict resolution uses *commit* timestamp, not the timestamp of an individual tuple insert/update/delete. See [`track_commit_timestamps`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-TRACK-COMMIT-TIMESTAMP) in the postgres docs.

In your example, node A might or might not see a conflict. If B's update happened first (according to B's clock), and B's update reaches A before C's does, A doesn't see a conflict. But if C's update reaches A before B's, and B's happened earlier, then when B's update arrives at A, A needs to know to discard it since it's already applied a newer one. Otherwise it'd become inconsistent with the state of B (which will apply C's update when it receives it) and C (which has overwritten B's older update with its own newer one).

Because it's a loosely coupled replication system with no global lock manager, snapshot manager, transaction manager, etc, there's no one concept of "now" and no one globally consistent state. Or at least it's fuzzy due to latency and replication lag. You'll see such systems ([somewhat incorrectly](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html)) referred to as "AP", for the "availability" and "partition tolerence" of [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem). It's an eventually consistent system with weaker inter-node guarantees than made by stock PostgreSQL. You can concurrently `UPDATE` a tuple on two different nodes. You can `INSERT` the same key into a `UNIQUE`-constrained column (or same `PRIMARY KEY`) on two different nodes. etc.

When the nodes replicate and sync up these conflicts need to be resolved so that all nodes have the same outcome and no errors result. We can't just ERROR because the xacts already committed on their origin nodes and we have no way to "un-commit" them; even if we did, we shouldn't, since other xacts on the local nodes might've used those committed changes as inputs into other computations so we're stuck with them.

So we have to do things like pick the newest of two inserts. We use the timestamp of commit for this. It's sent on the protocol messages, and it's recorded by postgres for local commits.

The old row values don't matter for this. For example, we only care that some peer node updated table "x" but we've updated it more recently, so we presume the newer update should be kept. Otherwise when our change replicated to the peer node, it'd apply our change and if we'd also applied theirs, we'd have different final states. To get a consistent result, we must discard their change.

Similarly, if two new rows are inserted, we must consistently pick one of them to keep when they conflict on the same PK. We pick the newest of the two rows based on recorded commit timestamp.

So yes, it relies on clocks. The clocks don't have to be in perfect sync, but roughly right is desirable, otherwise you might overwrite newer tuples with significantly older ones when doing conflict resolution, i.e. pick the wrong "last" update. The manual should discuss clock sync a bit more.

---

Having access to old row values would be *nice* in some cases, but is doesn't let you know for sure what the right outcome is. You still have to pick one of multiple possible "correct" results. Consider this:

given table

```
CREATE TABLE x (
  id integer primary key,
  y integer not null
);

INSERT INTO x (id, y) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Two nodes run

```
UPDATE x SET y = y + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

at the same time. Both produce a new local row with value `y = 2` as a result. Now each replicates to the other.

If we know the old value was 1 and the new value is 2, we might say "well, duh, the correct result is 3 on both nodes".

But we have *no way to know* that one or both nodes didn't instead run

```
UPDATE x SET y = 2;
```

instead of `y = y + 1`. So it might want the final result to be 2, not 3. The only way to know is to know the application logic. BDR can't tell based on just the old and new tuples.

So really we don't need the old tuple values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  We cannot have transactional consistency, but it would be nice to be able to be consistent within a set of related rows, parent & children.  But postgres has no such notion of parent foreign keys (nor does any other DB AFAIK).  So maybe one needs to go to NoSql if this is a requirement.

Comment: track_commit_timestamp -- Default is false.  Does that mean that by default it does not actually use the commit timestamp, and that it is important to set this option?

Comment: @Tuntable Why don't you try it and see? Or take a look at the manual. tip: BDR won't start with `track_commit_timestamp = off`.